# AJAX read file and erase content (not the file itself)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX script that is opening a file and reading its content every second:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filename = "/my/file/location.txt;
    console.log(filename);
    setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 10);
    function functionToLoadFile(){
            $.ajax({
                url: filename,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#content').append(data);
                    setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 1000);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#content').html("error receiving file");
                },
            });
    }
});
</script>
```

This is working properly, however I want it to also erase the content of the file every time the function runs. How would it be possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't be done with clientside code, you'd have to do the ajax call to the server and then do it there instead.

Comment: So basically I can make an AJAX call to a PHP file that would remove the content of the file. This sounds like a good solution too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is sending an AJAX request with a Get to the server. The server responds with this with loading the content of the file and serving it back directly.

This could even be seen as a security risk because everyone is able to navigate to this file directly from within their browser and read it.

Since the file is not actually on your local hard drive and you're not loading the file but instead issuing an HTTP request that causes the server to load the file and return its content, you can't delete it from the client side.

What you can do is add a server side method, `deleteFile(path)`, and then send a POST request to this URL. This will let the server then delete the file. You'll probably also want to add some form of security.

Comment: Thank you for the information. In that case I will write a PHP file to remove the contents and call it through the AJAX function.

Also, if you don't mind, can you please elaborate on the security part? I would love to learn more about what can be done.

Comment: Exposing a method on your PHP API that can be called with a regular HTTP post is not secure. Everyone can call your server method without any checks. I'm no expert in PHP but in the .NET world you would let the user authenticate and then attach a token to each request that would validate the user. I'm sure something similar exists for PHP but that's a question of its own.